# Any recommendations for lightweight .net Win Forms HTML renderer controls?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, controls

Trying to avoid the .net WebBrowser control (I don't need to navigate to a url, print rendered html or any of the other inbuilt goodies).  Wrapping the IE dll seems a bit heavyweight.

I simply require something that can display basic html marked up text - an html equivalent of [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) in effect.  Anyone have any experiences / recommendations / war stories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I developed this [HTML control for .NET](http://www.modeltext.com/html/), which does what you were asking: i.e. display basic html marked up text.

It doesn't use IE or any other unmanaged code (except for the .NET framework itself).

Comment: Building it as well as supplying it as an answer - that's got to be worth a +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Lutz Roeder (of Reflector fame) has a WYSIWYG HTML editor in .NET on his site here: http://www.lutzroeder.com/dotnet/.  Check out the download called "writer".  I haven't used it myself, but it was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: Looking at the source for Lutz Roeder's Writer, I see that his control is a wrapper around IE (i.e. MSHTML).

Answer (score 0):

While it takes a bit of effort, you can disable almost all of the 'extra' functionality of the built in WebBrowser control.

If the built in web browser provides all the functionality you need why look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[J. Menendez Poo's fully managed HTML renderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) isn't complete, but it's by far the best I've found.

I still have to try it in depth, but looks a lot more promising than the other alternative:

- [Bruce Shankle's Anole](http://www.bruceshankle.com/_mgxroot/page_10764.html)

This assuming you don't actually need the editing capability's of [Lutz Roeder's Writer](http://www.lutzroeder.com/dotnet/).

Comment: I edited the URL of the HTML renderer (now hosted on Codeplex), but Bruce Shankle's Anole is 404 without a forwarding address.

Comment: Looking at the source for Lutz Roeder's Writer, I see that his control is a wrapper around IE (i.e. MSHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/). I've had success with it in .net apps.